# Google Maps v3 marker with icon and image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to add markers on my Google Maps V3. I want to have similar markers as on Foursquare, where they join an icon and image (with JS) and create one big marker.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich marker perhaps?

[Rich Marker v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html)

PS. the copy of richmarker.js from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/io-2010-bootcamp/richmarker.html?r=204) worked better for me