# Adding code to pull in Dynamic names to google markers

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, google-maps, passport.js

I have a app that users have to login to via facebook and it then places them on a google_map

I want to connect the geolocated marker with the logged in user.

```
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              getContent(user.displayName)
              };
            });
```

https://github.com/5-minute-catchup/ANEWREPO

Comment: What's the problem? In the code above there isn't the marker code only a InfoWindow inside an infoWindow. Try to explain better

Comment: The problem is I am unsure how to connect the user logged in with the marker. Do I just add the code to the google marker? I have now pasted a link to me repo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation). So if the logged in user allows the permission (permission to share their location) then she can see the marker that represents her location. Otherwise, blankspace instead of map, if user denies permission.

Comment: thanks but yes I have got that far.. http://fivemincatchup.herokuapp.com/
But how to do I attach the login to the marker? You can see in my code above I tried getContent(user.displayName). Which does not work.

Comment: so adding the code doesn't work for users? any specific errors?

Comment: I would say a syntax issue

Comment: this may answer my question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do this is with custom markers and creating a function to call the data and put it into the custom markers.
see 
[JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)