# How to create a custom-shaped marker with images (Google Maps map API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I’m able to replace Google Map Markers with images :

I dynamically load users avatars on the map using this :

```
var icon = {
        // i get images url dynamically with html5 data attributes
        url: $marker.attr('data-icon'), // url

        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor


    };
```

Here is the result :

[image]

For now, it’s working but the graphic result is not what i want. I would like to have something like (i didn't design this example but you can see the idea) :

[image]

I was thinking of 3 possible solutions :

1- Create a polygon behind image in order to create a border and a kind of arrow.

2) Load 2 images : avatar image and behind graphic image of a custom pin (not sure it’s possible to load 2 images for a marker)

3) Add the possibility to have custom CSS for the markers like in this answer on this question  :

[JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)
demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/DVKEj/

What would be the best approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) This would pose a problem when zooming the map, you would anchor the image to specific position, anchor the polygon to specific position, but with zoom change they would no longer be synchronised.

2) No it's not possible to load two images for standard `google.maps.Marker`, if you wanted to go with this approach you would have to generate 1 image on backend by merging images of photo and frame and load that

3) Extending `google.maps.OverlayView` as per example you linked is the recommended way to go with custom looking markers. You can provide your own custom HTML/CSS/JS functionality to them, you cannot really get more freedom than that. You can learn more about overlays in the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays).

So definitely go with 3, Only situation when I would use 2) instead of 3) is when you would need to display more then 10000 markers at the same time, but even in that case, I would first give [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) a try.

Last but not least, check out [Google Maps Utility Libraries](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html), which provides you with some easy-to-use solutions for many usual tasks, for example you can use [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) for your problem, or [InfoBubble](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble) later if you wanted to add some custom looking bubble after clicking the markers.

Comment: I like your answer : you explain very well the solution i need to choose and the suggestion to use `js-rich-marker` is really easy.