# Modify sebm-google-map-marker using an angular2 directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-google-maps

I'm using angular2-google-maps https://angular-maps.com/ to build a google map with markers. What I'm trying to achieve is creating a marker which is customised with an users social media profile pic. I am going to use this: [JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)

To do this, i need to modify the marker code which i cannot access.

**Template:**

```
<sebm-google-map-marker
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lon"
  [appSocialMediaGoogleMapMarker]="'assets/img/temp/profile-image.png'"
  >
</sebm-google-map-marker>
```

**directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, MarkerManager, SebmGoogleMapMarker } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSocialMediaGoogleMapMarker]'
})
export class SocialMediaGoogleMapMarkerDirective {
  @Input('appSocialMediaGoogleMapMarker') socialMediaImage: string;

  constructor(
    el: ElementRef,
    private gmapsApi: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
    private markerManager: MarkerManager
  ) {

    this.gmapsApi.getNativeMap().then(map => {
      this.markerManager.getNativeMarker(el.nativeElement).then(marker => {

      });
    });

    console.log(this.socialMediaImage);

  }
}
```

The error i'm getting is

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

which is occuring on this line:

```
this.markerManager.getNativeMarker(el.nativeElement).then(marker => {
```

Also `this.socialMediaImage` if undefined.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Can you make a plunkr? `this.socialMediaImage` is undefined because I don't believe you can do what you do. You need to apply the directive first and then a seperate attribute for the input.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I used this page https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html as a reference and it uses html such as `<p [myHighlight]="color" defaultColor="violet">`. I'll add a message when I have created a plunkr.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking off functions. Anyway a plunkr will help with the debugging.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I've based this off an existing plunker and added in my directive. https://embed.plnkr.co/kGQ6lIh21kZHXhjrBoPq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also this.socialMediaImage if undefined.

Why do you expect this will not equal `undefined`? Why?

You're trying to get `@Input` property inside constructor. You need to use `ngOnInit` hook to get instantiated input property.

Then you can't get native marker from `nativeElement`

```
this.markerManager.getNativeMarker(el.nativeElement)
```

use the following:

```
import { SebmGoogleMapMarker } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

constructor(
  ...
  private sebmMarker: SebmGoogleMapMarker
) {}
...
this.markerManager.getNativeMarker(this.sebmMarker).then...
```

I created **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4HTvxOsqehh8tRPmeRU5?p=preview)** where you can play with it