# Rounded photo as Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have photos on the server:

- different sizes
- in a square

I would like to load them as a Marker, but I would like a photo in a circle

Below I have a code that loads the photo as a Marker, scales well but I don't know how to get the circular photo effect.

There is no specific and good solution on the Internet, and if something is, the entries are from several years ago.

```
const profileImage = {
  url:"@Model.LogoPath",
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
};

userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map,
  title: "Start",
  icon: profileImage
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Google map custom marker with css rounded corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367542/google-map-custom-marker-with-css-rounded-corner)

Comment: @MrUpsidown This is not a duplicate. The solution link you provided is from 7 years ago and is not working. And it's not about rounding a photo from a URL.

Comment: 1) It works 2) It's no different than your question (and answer) as it makes use of the OverlayView and explains how to use it 3) I marked it too as a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416883/how-add-circle-shape-in-google-maps-custom-icon) which has a working stack snippet for you to see and 4) both answers are for the same api version 3 that you are using 7 years later.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution:

1. Turn off optimization in Marker

   `optimized: false`
2. Add a layer with an image

   ```
   var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
   myoverlay.draw = function () {
       this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'myMarker';
   };
   myoverlay.setMap(map);
   ```
3. Add style to your image

   ```
   #myMarker img {
   border-radius: 100px;
   border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);
   }
   ```

All code:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        fullscreenControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        styles: CustomMapStyles
    });

    const myLatLng;

    const profileImage = {
        url:"http://qwerty.jpg",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    };

    userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map,
        title: "MyMarker",
        optimized: false,
        icon: profileImage
    });

    var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    myoverlay.draw = function () {
        this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'myMarker';
    };
    myoverlay.setMap(map);
}



#myMarker img {
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);
}
```